# Проблема html файла или Intelj Idea?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

```
<p th:text=`${Person.getName()}`>VALUE</p>
```

на браузере отобразится VALUE а не имя Person класса
в чем проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

При передаче значения при помощи thymeleaf нужно брать конструкцию ${...} в двойные кавычки, а не в одинарные:

```
<p th:text="${Person.getName()}"></p>
```

Так как все, что находится в одинарных кавычках преобразуется в строковое значение.

Comment: я так тоже пробовал не получается,отображается одно и то же